# Change column name Sequilize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to change default column name in my final output  which comes from Mysql database when i am accessing database using NodeJS and Sequelize connection.
I am connecting using following code:-

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";

    let dbConnection = new Sequelize('DB', 'abc', 'password', {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 4242,
        dialect: 'mysql',
        dialectOptions: {
            requestTimeout: 0,
        },
    });

const Listing = dbConnection.define('TableName', {
    tour_title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    }
}, { freezeTableName: true, timestamps: false });
```

For example, I want to change tour_title by tour_name in the above column only in the final sequelize output. I do not want any change in database column names.

Comment: Do you want an alias in the output or wanna change the column name in the database?

Comment: No, i dont want to change name in database. You can say i want an alias

Comment: Are you using `find()` or other relevant methods to get the records?

Answer (score 19):

**To change column name only in final output**

```
TableName.findAll({
  attributes: ['id', ['tour_title', 'tour_name']] /
})
.then((data) => {
 console.log(data);
});
```

**To change column name in database**

This may help you, follow this steps

Step 1: `npm install -g sequelize-cli`
To install sequelize command line tool

Step 2: `sequelize migration:create --name rename-column-tour_title-to-tour_name-in-tabelname`

Step 3: Open newly created migration file and add below code

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.renameColumn('tableName', 'tour_title', 'tour_name');
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.renameColumn('tableName', 'tour_name', 'tour_title');
  }
};
```

Step 4: in command line run this below command

```
sequelize db:migrate
```

Now your column name changed successfully.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak for a good solution but this changed the column name in database. But i want an updated name in final output only.

Comment: I'd add something to @Deepak 's answer. When I tried it the Step 4:  (I am a newbie), it prompted that
Cannot find `config.json` Have you run `sequelize init?` 
Then I ran that iniit command then it made a _config.json_ file inside the config folder

Answer (score 1):

If you want an `alias` for a column name in the ouput , you can do something like this:

```
TableName.findAll({
  attributes: ['id', ['tour_title', 'tour_name']] //id, tour_title AS tour_name
})
.then(function(data) {
  res.json(data);
});
```

Whenever you fetch any records you can write the column name in a cascaded list and make an alias.
Check for the documentation here : http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal did you cross check if you have all the above-listed fields in the database?The column names should match be same as mentioned in the code above.

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal do you have column "id" in the database table? if you don't have you should not write it in the attributes array.You can write the names of all the columns that exist in your table. Removing "id" from the array would resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers only works for the query results. If you want to keep your underscore name convention on the database and use for example camelCase for your javascript environment you need to do this:

```
const ChildTable = dbConnection.define('ChildTable', { //this table name is how you call it on sequelize
  tourTitle: { //this is the name that you will use on javascript
      field: 'tour_title', // this will be the name that you fetch on your db
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
  parentTableId: { // You need to define the field on the model, otherwise on sequelize you'll have to use the db name of the field
      field: 'parent_table_id', //this is defined above on the association part
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  }
}, { freezeTableName: true, timestamps: false, tableName: 'TableName', //this is the real name of the table on the db
underscored: true, });

ChildTable.associate = (models) => {
  ChildTable.belongsTo(models.ParentTable, {   as: 'ParentTable',   foreignKey: 'parent_table_id', onDelete: 'cascade' });
};
```

This way you have an "alias" for your fields on all the Sequelize / javascript environment and you keep your names on the db. See also that you have to do the same with the foreign keys on associations, otherwise you'll have to use the original name.

Comment: How do you specify "field" on associations? My columns are underscored but the associations are creating camelCase column names.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add something to `@Deepak`'s answer. When I tried it the `Step 4`:  (I am a newbie), it prompted that

"Cannot find `config.json` Have you run `sequelize init?` "

Then I executed that init command then it made a *config.json* file inside the config folder. So the file contained below objects.

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_development",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_production",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
}
```

Then I executed the `sequelize db:migrate`. It prompted another error as

```
Sequelize CLI [Node: 18.7.0, CLI: 6.4.1, ORM: 6.21.4]
Loaded configuration file "config\config.json".
Using environment "development".

ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Then what I did was I changed the config.json file to something like this -->

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "<this should include your root password>",
    "database": "<this should include your db>",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_production",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
}
```

And then migration was done successfully!